# How to input a variable value in field of name or id using blade template in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel-4, template-engine, laravel-blade

I need to input text name and id dynamically and I am trying as below

```
 {{ Form::text('practice', $practice->name, array('class' => 'large-2','id'=<?php echo $inputTextName;?>)) }}
```

But it is not parsing PHP here. Even I tried `'id'={{$inputTextName}}` but it is giving error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
 {{ Form::text('practice', $practice->name, array('class' => 'large-2','id'=>$inputTextName)) }}
```